# How to display the value of an XML attribute which is already selected using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

This is part of my XML file. The goal is to output a table containing each vegetarian item along with price and calories.

```
<Menu>
<MenuItem Price="4.95" Calories="450" IsVegetarian="false">Hamburger</MenuItem>
<MenuItem Price="5.50" Calories="300" IsVegetarian="true">Fruit Salad</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

The part that confuses me is the first line already selects each menu item and I'm not sure how to simply output it.

```
<xsl:for-each select="Menu/MenuItem">
   <xsl:if test="@IsVegetarian='true'">
      <tr>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="?????"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="@Price"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="@Calories"/></td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I've tried `<xsl:value-of select="Menu/MenuItem"/>` but that isn't working (I'm thinking because I already have `"Menu/MenuItem"` selected.) Is this the case? How can I output "Fruit Salad" from `<MenuItem>`?

Comment: Did you try `select="."`?

Comment: If there is no helpful answer I recommend to explain the problem in more detail. What do you need different? Maybe you would also enjoy taking the guided StackOverflow [tour].

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, it is "this" (easy to remember, as it is similar to the current working directory on a file system).

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```